# I am not able to update application on play store

Tags: android

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: CB:AD:B1:8A:A9:F9:FE:26:F8:09:64:A6:7C:BE:FA:3B:C0:3F:FB:CD
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: 1A:50:0E:7B:57:4D:91:B6:DD:65:9F:89:6C:11:FC:19:19:16:FF:86

Currently i am trying to update APK on play store but showing this error as I am generating APK from my computer but previously do same by someone else.

Comment: make sure you are trying to generate the app bundle using the same KeyStore file and credentials as previous one , if changed than playstore will not accept the update. If lost the KeyStore file then contact to play support to update the KeyStore/signing key and signing certificate

Comment: Keystore file is same as I have generated other flavor APK and uploading into play store but some of not uploading may be due to previously uploaded that application by other developer(from different computer)   .

Comment: which is best solution for this issue, as i have to request play store to reset signing or else ?

Comment: request playstore for the same

Comment: @Mr.Mad if I request to the play store for same can old application affected or not any idea ?

Comment: No it will not affect anything it will be same, but once they allow and reset the signing certificate with your new one then you will be able to update the app. But make sure you are the owner of the playstore account otherwise they will mot allow to reset the signing certificate.